# Cannot run sudo apt update on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on Google cloud

Tags: ubuntu, repository

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic

$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://asia-northeast1.gce.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://asia-northeast1.gce.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://asia-northeast1.gce.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
Ign:4 http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt google-cloud-monitoring-bionic InRelease
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [83.2 kB]
Hit:6 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Err:7 http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt google-cloud-monitoring-bionic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 172.217.25.238 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt google-cloud-monitoring-bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you may have run google's bugged Stackdriver Agent [install scripts](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/quickstart-lamp#install_the_stackdriver_agents).

The script will update `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-monitoring.list` even if the dist you are on (ie. bionic) is not in `https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/dists`

Also, `changing google-cloud-monitoring.list` to xenial (on bionic) will fail because of a `libcurl3` and `curl`<=`libcurl4` conflict.

Google should fix their script

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me that you have the wrong repository name. I don't see a `google-cloud-monitoring-bionic`.

Could it possibly be `google-cloud-monitoring-xenial`?

Browse through `https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/dists` with a web browser to view available repositories.

Comment: I want to try setting the repository name to `google-cloud-monitoring-xenial`. How can I do this?